# Where can I find the source code examples for "Introduction to 3D game programming with DirectX 9.0c"?

Tags: c++, directx, 3d, direct3d

I have a book : "Introduction to 3D game programming with DirectX 9.0c– a shader approach" by Frank Luna.

The official site is dead and I can't seem to find 3 main files used for all the projects.

- d3dApp.h
- d3dApp.cpp
- d3dUtil.h

Does someone know where can I get them?

All I have found was this :

- http://www.d3dcoder.net/
- http://www.d3dcoder.net/phpBB/

But there is no source there.
Also I've found some fragments

```
//A sample directX demo outputting some flashing color text

#include "d3dApp.h"
#include <tchar.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

//Our application is derived from the D3DAPP class, making setup for a game 
//or other program easier in the long run
class HelloD3DApp : public D3DApp
{
public:
    HelloD3DApp(HINSTANCE hInstance, std::string winCaption, D3DDEVTYPE devType, DWORD requestedVP);
    ~HelloD3DApp();

    bool checkDeviceCaps();
    void onLostDevice();
    void onresetDevice();
    void updateScene(float dt);
    void drawScene();

private:

    ID3DXFont* mFont;
};

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance,
                   PSTR cmdLine, int showCmd)
{
    // Enable run-time memory check for debug builds.
    #if defined(DEBUG) | defined(_DEBUG)
        _CrtSetDbgFlag( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
    #endif


    HelloD3DApp app(hInstance, "Hello Direct3D", D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING);
    gd3dApp = &app;

    return gd3dApp->run();
}

HelloD3DApp::HelloD3DApp(HINSTANCE hInstance, std::string winCaption, D3DDEVTYPE devType, DWORD requestedVP)
: D3DApp(hInstance, winCaption, devType, requestedVP)
{
    srand(time_t(0));

    if(!checkDeviceCaps())
    {
        MessageBox(0, "checkDeviceCaps() Failed", 0, 0);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }

    LOGFONTA font;
    font.lfHeight          = 80;
                font.lfWidth            = 40;
    font.lfEscapement       = 0;
    font.lfOrientation      = 0;
                font.lfWeight          = FW_BOLD;
                font.lfItalic          = true;
    font.lfUnderline        = false;
    font.lfStrikeOut        = false;
                font.lfCharSet        = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
                font.lfOutPrecision  = OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS;
    font.lfClipPrecision    = CLIP_CHARACTER_PRECIS;
                font.lfQuality        = DEFAULT_QUALITY;
                font.lfPitchAndFamily   = DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE;
               _tcscpy(font.lfFaceName, _T("Times New Roman"));

    HR(D3DXCreateFontIndirect(gd3dDevice, &font, &mFont));
}

HelloD3DApp::~HelloD3DApp()
{
    ReleaseCOM(mFont);
}

bool HelloD3DApp::checkDeviceCaps()
{
    // Nothing to check.
    return true;
}

void HelloD3DApp::onLostDevice()
{
    HR(mFont->OnLostDevice());
}

void HelloD3DApp::onresetDevice()
{
    HR(mFont->onresetDevice());
}

void HelloD3DApp::updateScene(float dt)
{
}

void HelloD3DApp::drawScene()
{
    HR(gd3dDevice->Clear(0, 0, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255), 1.0f, 0));

    RECT formatRect;
    GetClientRect(mhMainWnd, &formatRect);

    HR(gd3dDevice->BeginScene());

    mFont->DrawText(TEXT("Hello </DIC>!"), -1, 
        &formatRect, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER, 
        D3DCOLOR_XRGB(rand() % 256, rand() % 256, rand() % 256));

    HR(gd3dDevice->EndScene());
    HR(gd3dDevice->Present(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

But these does not help me either.

Comment: The other website listed on the back cover that you didn't mention, is still actually available on the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20080630070201/http://www.wordware.com/files/dx9c/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[d3dApp.h](http://read.pudn.com/downloads94/sourcecode/graph/375480/CloudDemo/d3dApp.h__.htm)

[d3dApp.cpp](http://read.pudn.com/downloads94/sourcecode/graph/375480/CloudDemo/d3dApp.cpp__.htm)

[d3dUtil.h](http://read.pudn.com/downloads94/sourcecode/graph/375480/CloudDemo/d3dUtil.h__.htm)

These are the same files as in the zip file.

Comment: Well, thanks for trying, but this is not the right code. The code I need was on the official website written by Frank Luna.

Comment: I've also found those, but these ones are not original, they are modified by users, thus not working with only 3 files. I guess they are not easy to be found.

Comment: The site you linked to, [www.d3dcoder.net](http://www.d3dcoder.net/), has a link to a zip file called [Source Code Part II](http://www.d3dcoder.net/Data/Book2/PartII.zip) which contains the 3 files you need in almost every subfolder. Did you check those? They seems to be original as I found them elsewhere on the web.

Comment: Thank you so much, I overlooked it. Now I can continue learning.